# Jquery animation callback problems

Tags: jquery

Im trying to use a callback on this animation so the image being animated goes back to its original state after the animation is complete. But its not working properly. Can someone show me how to do this with the correct syntax please?

```
if (currentEffect == "glimpse") {
    $("#next").click(function () {
        if (currentSlide == 0) {
            $("#slide1").animate({
                width: "0",
                opacity: 0.2,
                borderWidth: "10px"
            }, 1000, function () {
                width: "700px"
                opacity: 100,
                borderWidth: "0px"
            });
            $("#slide2").fadeIn(800);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (currentEffect == "glimpse") {
    $("#next").click(function () {
        if (currentSlide == 0) {
            $("#slide1").animate({
                width: "0",
                opacity: 0.2,
                borderWidth: "10px"
            }, 1000, function () {
                $(this).animate({  // <-- need to call .animate() again
                    width: "700px" // <--- you forgot a ,
                    opacity: 100,  // <--- opacity is a value between 0.0 and 1.0
                    borderWidth: "0px"
                }, 1000);
            });
            $("#slide2").fadeIn(800);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function is not referencing an object. You probably want:

```
$("#slide1").animate({
    width: "0",
    opacity: 0.2,
    borderWidth: "10px"
}, 1000, function () {
    $("#slide1").css({ 
        width: "700px",
        opacity: 1, 
        borderWidth: "0px"
    });
});
```